# Issue with Objection.js Relation Mapping

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, objection.js

I am currently working on setting up a relationship in Objection.js between the Article and Chat models in my application. I have encountered an error related to the relation mapping, specifically in the definition of the join.from property.

```
channels: {
  relation: BaseModel.HasManyRelation,
  modelClass: Chat,
  join: {
    from: (builder) => {
      if (builder.parentModel().parent_id !== null) {
        return 'article.parent_id';
      }
      return 'article.id';
    },
    to: 'Chat.articleId',
  },
},
```

```
The error message I'm receiving is: Article.relationMappings.Chat: join.from must have format TableName.columnName. For example "SomeTable.id".
```

I've tried several approaches to resolve this error, but none of them seem to work. If anyone has experience with Objection.js or has encountered a similar issue, I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions you might have to offer.